# ng-bind not showing anything after API call sets data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, soundcloud

This is my code, and the username is not showing up in my DOM.
After the soundcloud API is initiated, the data is loading using a SC.get call, the callback function within sets the $scope.user to the response.

If i check my browser nothing will show up, any ideas solving this?

```
<div ng-controller="trackCtrl">
    <p ng-bind="user.username"></p>
</div>

function trackCtrl($scope)
{
    $scope.initialize = function() {
        console.log('initialize');
        SC.initialize({
            client_id: "CLIENT_ID",
            redirect_uri: "http://soundcloud.dev/app/callback.html",
        });

        SC.get('/users/marioochoa/', function(user) {
            $scope.user = user;
            $scope.getTracks();
        });
    };

    $scope.getTracks = function() {
        console.log('getTracks');
    };

    $scope.initialize();
};
```

Comment: <p>{{user.username}}</p> perhaps

Comment: That does the same and gave me the same problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the `SC.get` callback is invoked from "outside" Angular, you need to manually trigger a digest cycle so Angular updates the view. In order to do that you should call `$scope.$apply()`:

```
SC.get('/users/marioochoa/', function(user) {
  $scope.$apply(function() {
    $scope.user = user;
    $scope.getTracks();
  });
});
```

You can find more information on that matter [here](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/concepts).

Comment: I suggest that you follow @JeroenIngelbrecht advice and replace `ng-bind` with `{{ expression }}`. Both do the same thing but the latter is less verbose. Unless, of course, you are using `ng-bind` to prevent the browser from momentarily showing the raw expression before Angular compiles it.

Comment: Thanks, i knew that ;-). Don't you think there must be some way of preventing the {{ expression }} to be shown before compiling?

Comment: As a matter of fact, there is a way to do that: the `ng-cloak` directive. http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngCloak